# How Pass Token in every Request

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I'm using [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) And I want to pass this token in every Request.

Have I set my Token in Session and pass the session with token `app.use`?

or I have to Store it in Cookie?

Can I Retrieve the logged user by JWT?

I create my Token with

```
 var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('superSecret'), {
                    expiresIn: 1440 // expires in 24 hours
                });
```

and Check The Token With

```
 jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function(err, decoded) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });
                } else {
                    // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                    req.decoded = decoded;
                    next();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Pass token from where? From browser? If yes, why are you using tokens? This is not how tokens are supposed to be used.

Comment: @Vohuman I want to pass my token in each request, and Don't want to pass by browser. I don't know the best way to store the token and the user, and use them in the the middleWare to check if the user is logged

Comment: Does an external API generate the token? Passing token from where to where?

Comment: no, The token is generate by user and secret string `jwt.sign(user, app.get('superSecret')`

Comment: @Vohuman Where Jwt save the informations?

Comment: Nowhere. It simply returns the generated token. Tokens differ from sessions. You can store the token in database or in your session driver, but it's not the point of using tokens. User logs in, server returns the token and on each request the sent token from client is read/validated by the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91975/discussion-between-monkeyuser-and-vohuman).